# How to make games with WPF or Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

How do I make games in WPF and in C#? Is there a document in PDF format that explains this?

Comment: Yes.  It's called the Internet.

Comment: @Pierreten: Try to be a bit more constructive and specific. Thanks.

Comment: 5 times upvoted the hint to the internet... where can you download the internet as pdf? Also, is SO not the internet? Since the internet has the answers, SO is really really obsolete, don't you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could read the articles posted on [Silverlight Games 101](http://www.bluerosegames.com/silverlight-games-101/), as a starting point.

That being said, it's more just learning how to write games.  Using WPF/Silverlight is just one way to render your game - but writing the game is pretty much going to require all of the same skills as using other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Google [this name](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198929). The title of the book is "3D Game Development with Microsoft Silverlight 3: Beginner's Guide".

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2D (sprite based) port of the XNA framework to Silverlight called [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/) The same tutorials that work for XNA work for this library.

Answer (score 0):

Using WPF to create games is not recommended. You should consider using cocos2d, unity or another similar framework.

If you really have to use WPF, you can see an example here => [mini wpf game](https://github.com/VladTsiukin/KillKenny)